# How to create multiple correlated random numbers using MultivariateNormalDistribution class?

Tags: java, math, statistics

I have tried to generate multiple correlated random numbers with the following code:

```
MultivariateNormalDistribution mnd = new MultivariateNormalDistribution(means,    
covariances);
double vals[] = mnd.sample();
```

Unfortunately, after several runs I had to realize the numbers I get are not correlated at all. The covariance matrix doesn't seem to influence the distribution.

Is there any way I could have misunderstood the method and can somebody explain how to use the method properly?

Amk,
Jamal

Answer (score 0):

Let x have a multivariate Gaussian distribution with mean 0 and covariance = I where I is the m-dimensional identity matrix with m = number of dimensions of x. Let S be a positive definite matrix, and let L be a lower-triangular matrix such that L . transpose(L) = S. (That is, L is a Cholesky decomposition of S.) Then L x is multivariate Gaussian distributed with mean 0 and covariance S.

If you add any vector mu to L x, then mu + L x has a Gaussian distribution with mean mu and covariance S.

A sample from an m-dimensional Gaussian with mean 0 and covariance = I is just a list (x_1, ..., x_m) where each x_i is 1-dimensional Gaussian with mean 0 and variance 1.